# UILabel Gesture Respond

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

    func titleStyle(){
    imageTitle.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            imageTitle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
            imageTitle.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0

            // Apply Gesture to label
            imageTitle.userInteractionEnabled = true
            imageTitle.tag = 10
            imageTitle.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappedLabel"))
        }
```

Some how this code doesn't seem to work when the label is tapped.

```
func tappedLabel(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){
        print("Hi")
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a tap gesture recogniser?

Answer (score 4):

I think you have missed ":" while adding action.

```
imageTitle.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappedLabel:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be in using a `UIGestureRecognizer` instead of a `UITapGestureRecogniser`

Try:

```
imageTitle.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappedLabel:"))
```

I'm not 100% sure why using a `UIGestureRecognizer` doesn't work, but I hit the same issue myself, and this worked for me.